# 2010: Query String URL Filter doesn't filter until postback

Tags: 2010, filter, tasks, query-string

I have a Query String URL filter sending a value (ProjectID) to a task list which filters the tasks down to match the query string. On page load, however, all tasks are displayed, making it seem that the filter is not working. BUT when a postback occurs, the filter works perfectly and only the related tasks appear.

I have no idea what would be causing this.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what is causing it. However, you could try the alternative below.

Please try this query string syntax (no need for the filter webpart):

?filterField1=ProjectID&filterValue1=myFilterValue

Using these query string parameters all list items on the page containing the ProjectID column will be filtered to show only items where this column has The value myFilterValue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works when I'm viewing the Task list page but not when I have a webpart of the task list on another page. I think I fixed the problem by reconfiguring the query string filter.

Comment: @PTRFRLL Good to hear! Look forward to hearing what solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bug. I bet you have the server rendering disabled.

Edit the webpart, under miscellaneous (not sure if in english it is called so) check the `server rendering`.

I know that the layout of a server rendered listview is not really nice, but it's (AFAIK) the only way to fix the problem.